# Swashbuckle/Swagger + ASP.Net Core: "Failed to load API definition"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I develop an ASP.NET Core 2 application and included Swagger. Everything worked fine until I introduced a method without explicitly defining the HTTP action:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("/error")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new Error("Internal error."));
    }
}
```

When I started the app with this method, the following message showed up:

> Failed to load API definition.
>
> Errors
> Fetch error Internal Server Error /swagger/v1/swagger.json

As soon as I explicitly set e.g. `[HttpGet]` the error disappears. The problem with this is, I need this method to fire for all possible HTTP operations.
Of course, I could specify all operations explicitly, but I have the feeling Swagger should be able to handle this correctly.

Why does Swagger behave this way?

Is there any configuration I can use?

Comment: ' I need this method to fire for all possible HTTP operations' why will you need to support all methods, rather than only GET?

Comment: Can you share your Swashbuckle configuration?

Comment: @Set in this case the `Error` endpoint is used as the exception handler. Depending on the HTTP operation of the request, the according operation on the `Error` endpoint is called.

Comment: @HelderSepu the config is pretty straight forward:
`services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
 c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My Service", Version = "v1" });
});

app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
 c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) => swagger.Host = httpReq.Host.Value);
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
 c.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; // serve the UI at root
 c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
});`

Comment: I managed to reproduce your issue, looks like a Bug in the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, the `ResolveConflictingActions` should work

Comment: @HelderSepu the code you provided in your comment above worked for me. I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore(3.0.0) and AspNetCore.All(2.0.9).

Comment: In my case this happened because i was using same route for two apis, so corrected it to use unique for each api, then it worked.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The option [ResolveConflictingActions](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/86cc761bc4f5dda796f80ad8dfd8bc205542a6f6/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/Application/SwaggerGenOptions.cs#L75) should be working on this case...

Here is the actual error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action
```

That is coming from:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/86cc761bc4f5dda796f80ad8dfd8bc205542a6f6/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/Generator/SwaggerGenerator.cs#L90

I think this is a bug, if you are truly interested you should report it to the project

Comment: For ASP.net core 3 I had to add the ResolveConflictingActions into my AddSwaggerGen section in startup >     c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());

Comment: Yups, in my case I kept same URL for two different APIs.

Comment: In my case, I defined two [HttpGet] in my  ApiController and Swagger get confused, but if I define [HttpGet("myMethod1")] and [HttpGet("myMethod2")], then, swagger understands. I see  ResolveConflictingActions only as a patch. Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 118):

Make sure each public controller method has:

- either Httpxxx(`[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, ...) attribute for Action methods,
- or `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` for methods which aren't controller actions

Comment: This worked in my case: there were a couple of public Action methods that used GET, but not explicitly so

Comment: Because this answer is helpful to people to come to this page for the error, even if the cause is not identical to the OP

Comment: The use of [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] works perfectly, when I needed it for a "/Error" routing only. Thanks!

Answer (score 88):

Simply you can look into the log in the **Output** window. The actual error can be seen there. In my case, I missed adding HTTP action on top of a methods

[image]

Comment: yes, when swagger load press f12 and then we have got more details :)

Comment: This helped me find the answer. The problem was a `public` helper method in a controller. Changed it to `protected` - swagger file generates again.

Answer (score 51):

Instead of blindy guessing what could be the issue, navigate to

`http://localhost:PORT/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

[image]

In my case this could have been resolved by using the
c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);

which is a horrible workaround, but might be a quick fix for someone in need. My solution was to rename and clarify the path for those endpoints

Comment: This helped me a lot! Navigated to http://localhost:PORT/swagger/v1/swagger.json and got a much more detailed error message.

Comment: Same as @JohanThorild - the JSON error message pointed to a public method in my controller that Swagger thought was an API call. Changed it to private -- fixed!

Comment: correct, must navigate to json location to get error message

Answer (score 21):

I don't know if this has been resolved or not but one way you can go about this is by decorating the method with:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

This will ensure that the method in question is ignored by Swagger.

Answer (score 17):

Another possible issue is that the endpoint needs to be complete from the domain root.

I had:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
});
```

I had to use:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c=>
{
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/myApi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");

});
```

Comment: another solution is to use `c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");`. This should work for both relative and absolute urls.

Comment: this is what i caused my issue

Comment: This `c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");` worked for me.

Comment: Same here, I added the leading '/' and it worked. Not sure why though, my other microservices don't have it. `opts.SwaggerEndpoint("/v1/download/swagger.json", "Download");` Edit: It looks like it was a trailing '/' on one of my controllers. `
[Route("api/v1/my-endpoint/")]`

Answer (score 13):

In ASP.NET Core, if there is a controller endpoint like:

```
[Route("images")]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
```

This can also fail with fetch failed. The solution is to have something like

```
[HttpGet("images/{id}")]
```

Same thing goes for HttpPost.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Helder Sepulvedas answer and from 'Monte-Christos' answer in this github issue - [Actions require unique method/path combination for Swagger](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/390)

> I found the place to configure ResolveConflictingActions in ASP.NET
>   Core apps. In your Setup class, add this to the ConfigureServices()
>   method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
  { 
    other configs...;
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
  });
```

This done the trick for me!

Answer (score 8):

The default api controller route configuration is the cause of this issue. When we add the API controller in the ASP.NET Core API application, by default it has controller-specific routes, which means it can support only a single method for each of the HTTP verbs Post, PUT, Delete, GET, and Patch.

There may be a requirement when we need to create more than one method having the Http verbs Post, PUT, Delete, GET, and Patch in a single controller, and if you create the method with the default route configuration, then you will get the following error while loading the Swagger UI.

[image]

The solution is that you have to change the default route configuration at the controller level when you have created more than one method with the HTTP verbs "post," "put," and "get." Delete or Put in the single API controller class.

Consider the following example: I have created the ASP.NET Core API application, which has by default one Get method, GetWeatherForecast, which returns the WeatherForecast. Then I have added one more Get method named WeatherForecastByCity in the default API Controller class without modifying the default route.

```
 [ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "WeatherForecastByCity")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(string city)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

When we have run the application, we will get the Swagger loading error,

[image]

Now change the default route at controller level which can support more than one method having the Http verbs Post, PUT, Delete, GET, and Patch in a single controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Also, remove the name of the method from the HTTP verb, which is defined using the Name attribute; just define the HTTP verb and proper method name.

Change from

```
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

To

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetWeatherForecast()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

Full Code

```
 [ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetWeatherForecast()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

     [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecastByCity(string city)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Now, run the application again after changing the default route, and you will see swagger loads without any issue.

[image]

Comment: This was my case and the answer was very helpful.

Comment: This worked for me, and I feel is more of a common resolving action than the other possibilities as outlined in the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

Swagger also throws the same exception if there are public methods that are not actions in a controller. The fix is to make all of them `protected` or `private` or as mentioned add the attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`.

Comment: I had a base class to the controllers with a public helper function and your suggestion solved the issue by making it `protected`.

Answer (score 5):

in my case i use this code as like as .net code

```
[ActionName("Login")]
[HttpPost]
```

now i change it for use on net core web api

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
```

And it works right

Answer (score 4):

Guess what... started getting this error page "`Failed to load API definition`":

[image]

By looking at the app's console or the output window in Visual Studio it told me the following:

[image]

I added a [public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/public) method called Client to the Web API `BaseController` and ***Swagger*** was thinking it should be included in the API.

To solve the problem: mark that method as [protected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected):

[image]

Comment: Nice debugging tip to go to the console, I had missed it initially. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. In my case, All of my controllers inherited from a **BaseController**. in this base class, I got a public action which returns UserId according to Claims. I set the **[NonAction]** attribute on the top of this action.

```
[ApiController]
[ApiResultFilter]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{

    [NonAction]
    public int GetCurrentUserId()
    {
        return int.Parse(this.User.Claims.First(p => p.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## This is answer 32 so there is a variety of reasons!

### -> You need to troubleshoot efficiently

Solutions differ from some only working for NSwag/Swashbuckle to different versions of Swashbuckle to adding JsonIgnore of Newtonsoft vs built in or adding the BindNever attribute which all might or might not help but for sure it costs time!

Before you start: Check if there is maybe an exception or error message in debug console. This might speed you up the most. Sometimes there is none!

#### Speedy troubleshooting guide:

1. All your Controllers should have a [ApiController] attribute (if not consider adding it) so **search and replace `[ApiController]` with `[ApiController][ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`** to make them invisible for SwaggerGen

##### OptionA - Working now without any api controllers:

2. Open your favorite Git tool that has a user interface and **dismiss half of the changes in git** until swagger loads https://127.0.0.1:12345/swagger/index.html again and that way rule it down to a single controller that breaks swashbuckle
3. Comment out all Get/Post/Put/Delete actions within this single controller and check if it is working.
4. Comment back in half of that actions until it is no longer working and that way rule it down to a single action
5. Comment out the whole content of the Action and just `return Ok();` to see if response is the problem.
6. Try with a replacement request class that just has a fraction of the props and narrow it down to a property causing the problem.

##### OptionB - Still not working even without any api controllers:

1. Try to reproduce with a fresh minimal project using the same package version and make the new project more and more similar to your big one. Your problem is likely already the initialisation which might be broken e.g. due to breaking changes or incompatibility within packages.

##### When you have the root cause the solution is often obvious

Possible root causes I have seen:

- A property of type "Type" in the request POCO which was failing without leaving any hint about what the problem is. The solution was to change it to a function which even made more sense than how it was.
- A class with the same name in 2 different namespaces

If you know how to improve this guide write it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this error because i created a controller which dosent have `[Route("api/[controller]")]`. After putting it, the error went away.

```
app.UseSwagger()
   .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
   {
       c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DOA.API V1");
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Double check , if you have used same `url name` in your same `controller`. It was happened to my `code`

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is adding `[NonAction]` attribute to the `public` methods that are not API calls in my controller wrapper.

Comment: In my case, public method from my BaseController should have change from public to protected. But your method was inspiration for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the error mentioned in the question and didn't find in answers the simple reason like:

**Endpoints should have unique routes i.e. distinct by name, VERB etc.**

[image]

Swagger is struggled when 2 endpoints routs looks the same

Check recently added endpoint(s) if they are not duplicating from routing perspective (name, verbs etc.)

in my case i was experimenting and did a copy-paste like this:

[image]

once i've made them distinct routes, Swagger was ok

[image]

the solution is simply specify a unique route

Answer (score 1):

My error reason was that same url name,

```
 [HttpGet("get/LeaveCommand/{id}")]
```

I use same url and swagger cannot get them

```
 [HttpGet("get/LeaveCommand/{id}")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. I checked and applied all of the solutions for swagger config but the issue still remained.
Finally, I checked the output panel and the problem was because of `[DefaultValue("SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()")]`.

The answer is here: **Check the output panel and you will find the answer**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

And the logs.....

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Count cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'count')
```

And in my case, the `Route` definition was wrong.

**Before  (returns error)**
Note the lack of {curly braces} in the `Route` definition.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("id:guid")]
```

**After (all good - no error)**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:guid}")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting below error in .net core web api:

`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Failed to generate Operation for action - WebApplication9.Controllers.AnimalsController.Post (WebApplication9). See inner exception`

**Solution:**

Make sure to use the different class/name per models, I was passing the same name with different properties. So swagger json schemas wasn't identifying the correct one.

**Example:**

UserController.cs

```
[HttpPost, Route("Create")]
public IActionResult Create(CreateRequest model) {}
```

PersonController.cs

```
[HttpPost, Route("Create")]
public IActionResult Create(CreateRequest model) {}
```

So, we need to use different models as parameter such as `UserCreateRequest` and  `PersonCreateRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Swagger is necessary to add [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] in your code like this:

```
    [Route("/error")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public IActionResult HandleError() =>
        Problem();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that I encountered for this error was the same API name for 2 methods in the same controller.

I suffixed the other method to _v2 and the swagger opened up properly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Cheers,
Tanjot

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34781502)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a `TypeLoadException` on a class that I was deleting that was unused. The fix in my case was to delete the bin/obj/Debug folder contents. Clean solution + rebuild solution did not fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because of Newtonsoft.Json in my case. But the thing is I was not using it. One of the packages may be depend on it but I did not have time to check.

So just check the output panenl solve the related issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your models (request or response) properties of type which inherits/implements types like `System.ComponentModel` (or other types) this will throw an error

```
"The JSON property 'item' is defined multiple times on type"...
```

Try to ignore this property using `[JsonIgnore]` attribute of `Newtonsoft.Json`

In my case i had a getter of type `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

In the Startup file you need to make sure that you add

```
services.AddSwaggerDocument();
```

before you add

```
app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3();
```

or it can result in this error

> Fetch error undefined /swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json

Answer (score 0):

for core 3 I had the same issue and was really confused that problem was in slash.

Configuration was:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "my-API", Version = "v1" });
            });
```

This swagger endpoint threw the message of TS:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/v1/swagger.json", "my-API v1");
            });
```

And finally I got it worked with removing the first slash in the URL:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "my-API v1");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was having registering swagger after `MapControllers` middleware. Once I moved before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a very simple issue, i had 3 [HttpGet] methods which turned out i needed to change the "createOrder" method to a [HttpPost]

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Order>>> GetOrders()
        {
            return await _context.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderItems).Where(x => x.BuyerId == User.Identity.Name).ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetOrder")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> GetOrder(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderItems).Where(x => x.BuyerId == User.Identity.Name && x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> CreateOrder(CreateOrderDto orderDto)
        {
            var basket = await _context.Baskets.RetrieveBasketWithItems(User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            var items = new List<OrderItem>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was solved by adding the HttpGet attribute and removing the index methods.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was caused by lazy/frustrated refactoring and I was able to determine the issue by reading the debug console when running the API in debugger mode.

Due to the bad refactoring, I ended up with two models with the same name, and Swagger was getting confused.

I had something like:

```
PROJECT
├───Auth
│       AutheController.cs
│       UserDto.cs
│
└───Controllers
    │   MyContrller.cs
    │
    └───Models
            UserDto.cs
```

Having two `UserDto` models is what was confusing Swagger. Cleaning this up fixed the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you methods in controller are marked with [HttPost] and/or [HttpGet]

Answer (score 0):

use the [HttpGet("Post")] or [HttpGet("Get")] in your Actions

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using enums in your object class (get, put, or post) also causes this issue.

By removing the line below in my

> AddJsonOptions

I had it resolved.

```
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
```