# Failed to load API definition, Fetch error: undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

this error occurred and I tries all the possible solutions on all sites and still not working
I tries swaggeroperation
I tries Route
I tries HttpGet("List/{id}")
nothing worked for me
Error details are:

```
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - MandobX.API.Controllers.ShipmentOperationsController.GetShipmentOperations (MandobX.API). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My code:
controllers Actions:

```
//Get lists of drivers, regions and packagges type to create shipment operation
        [Route("Init")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> InitShipment()
        {
            ShipmentViewModel shipmentInitViewModel = new ShipmentViewModel
            {
                Drivers = await _context.Drivers.Include(d => d.User).Include(d => d.Vehicle).ToListAsync(),
                PackageTypes = await _context.PackageTypes.ToListAsync(),
                Regions = await _context.Regions.ToListAsync()
            };
            return Ok(new Response { Code = "200", Data = shipmentInitViewModel, Msg = "Task Completed Succesfully", Status = "1" });
        }
        // GET: api/ShipmentOperations
        [SwaggerOperation("List")]
        [Route("List")]
        [HttpGet("List/{userId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ShipmentOperation>>> GetShipmentOperations()
        {
            return await _context.ShipmentOperations.ToListAsync();
        }

        [SwaggerOperation("Details")]
        [Route("Details")]
        [HttpGet("Details/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ShipmentOperation>> GetShipmentOperation(string id)
        {
            var shipmentOperation = await _context.ShipmentOperations.FindAsync(id);

            if (shipmentOperation == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return shipmentOperation;
        }
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

the answer was on github on this post
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/982
the solution is making the route annotation responsible for the generated route like this:

```
        [Route("List/{userId}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ShipmentOperation>>> 
        GetShipmentOperations(string userId)
        {
            return await _context.ShipmentOperations.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/ShipmentOperations/5
        [Route("Details/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ShipmentOperation>> GetShipmentOperation(string id)
        {
            var shipmentOperation = await _context.ShipmentOperations.FindAsync(id);

            if (shipmentOperation == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return shipmentOperation;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]

I have controller methods that are not end-points and they din't have any HttpGet or HttpPost at the top. I've added [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] at each controller method, which does not act as end-point and it worked as it should be.
The issue is also discussed here:
[Swashbuckle/Swagger + ASP.Net Core: "Failed to load API definition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209122/swashbuckle-swagger-asp-net-core-failed-to-load-api-definition?page=2&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top)